# Print year/month/day in Python?`

Tags: python

How do I print the current date in the below format?

year/month/date

I have been using the below, but it is adding an extra space.  I need it to look like this '2020/9/14' and not like '2020 / 9 / 14.  Any ideas?  Below is current code for the latter option.

```
str(todays_date.year)
str(todays_date.month)
str(todays_date.day)
dash = "/"
str(dash)

print(todays_date.year,dash,todays_date.month,dash,todays_date.day)
```

Comment: This question is slightly different than the one noted as being a duplicate.  The duplicate both A) Puts leading zeros on one-digit date components, and 2) may not be addressing the real question here at all if the OP is asking about string formatting....not that that doesn't mean that this is a dup of some other existing question.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.today().strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d'))
```

UPDATE: I added the hyphens in there, realizing that you didn't want the leading zero on a one-digit month or day.

Today's result:

```
2020/9/14
```

If you want to use the individual values from the date and do your own formatting, you can do this to get the same result:

```
print("{}{}{}{}{}".format(todays_date.year,dash,todays_date.month,dash,todays_date.day))
```

Comment: #Complete the code below. We've gone ahead and created
#variables for the current date and current time. Now,
#we want to print date with the format year/month/day,
#and the time with the format hour:minute:second.
#


from datetime import date
import datetime
todays_date = date.today()


#Complete the line below to print today's date with the
#form year/month/day. For example, January 15th, 2016
#would be 2016/1/15.

Comment: Strange.  This text talks about creating variables, but the only variable created in what you posted is the `dash` variable.  There's no sign of where `todays_date` comes from.  Those other four lines wrapping `str()` around existing quantities do nothing.

Comment: year_as_string = str(todays_date.year)
month_as_string = str(todays_date.month)
day_as_string = str(todays_date.day)
print(todays_date.year,"/",todays_date.month,"/",todays_date.day)

this prints with the spaces

Answer (score -1):

this:

```
date = '2020 / 09 /14'

print(date.replace(' ',''))
```

prints:

```
'2020/09/14'
```

Comment: Their date appears to be inside of a datetime object, not inside of a string that looks like that.

Comment: Also, the extra spaces the OP is referring to is comes from default argument for `separator` in the `print` function, not the actual `str` itself

Comment: OP never mentioned that they were dealing with a datetime object. The question asked how to remove spaces from the string. quickest solution is to remove the spaces using the code I provided, and then converting to a datetime object from there.